# Position Absolute z-index overlay doesn't work in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a div that is absolutely positioned over another div to provide some sort of overlay:

```
<div id="main_container">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <p>This is a product title</p>
    <img src="http://cdn-images.farfetch.com/10/63/37/08/10633708_3137969_400.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#main_container {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.61);
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
```

The problem is that this doesn't work in IE8  http://jsfiddle.net/BLEcP/

My question is, is it possible to have an absolutely positioned overlay with higher z-index work in IE8?

Thanks

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-ie-z-index/

Comment: also you cant use rgba colors in ie8 thats why your background is not shown. Check this link for the support: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: @Paulie_D I've read that tip, but from what I understand doesn't z-index only apply to absolute elements? I only have one absolute element and that's the overlay

Comment: @BillK Yea I know that background won't show up, but I'm fine with that. I just need the overlay to be present so users can't click through straight to the elements below

Comment: @user2028856 To answer the above question, it can be applied to any positioned element.

Comment: As `rgba()` isn't recognized by IE8- (as stated by @BillK), your element is empty. You must use a semi-transparent PNG (Fireworks FTW by example) or maybe an `#RRGGBB + opacity`. The z-index part works perfectly fine, see http://jsfiddle.net/BLEcP/2/ (tested on an original IE8@W7)

Comment: Thank You @FelipeAls for explaining so clearly, works perfectly :) can you put this as the answer so I can accept it  :D